# Prove: $\sum_ixL_i(x) = x$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Let $L_i(x)$ Lagrange polynomials $\prod_{i\neq j}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$ for $n+1$ points $x_0,x_1,...,x_n$

a. prove that for all $x$ $$\sum_{i=0}^nL_i(x)=1$$

b. prove: if $n\geq 1$, for all $x$

$$\sum_{i=0}^nxL_i(x)=x$$

So I proved a by interpolating the function $f(x)=1$ and using the fact that the interpolation polynomial is unique.

for b, can we say that because the coefficients of lagrange does not depend on the $y$ values, for the same points we can multiply the interpolation polynomial we got at a to get:

$$x=x\sum_{i=0}^nL_i(x)\Rightarrow x=\sum_{i=0}^nxL_i(x)$$

Comment: (b) is just (a) multiplied with $x$. Don't you think you could benefit from posting the definition of the $L_i$ in your question?

Comment: Is (b) written correctly? Perhaps it's $\sum_{i=0}^ny_iL_i(x_i)=x_i$?

Comment: @amsmath added the definition

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, it is for all $x$ , $\sum_{i=0}^nxL_{i}(x)=x$

Comment: It is probably meant to be $\sum_{i=0}^nx_iL_i(x)=x$. It follows from the fact that for any polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$ you have that $q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^np(x_i)L_i(x)$ is also of degree at most $n$ and $p(x_i)=q(x_i)$, $i=0,...,n$, so that the difference $p(x)-q(x)$ has to be the zero polynomial.

Comment: If it is  $\sum_{i=0}^n xL_i(x) = x$, then that follows from the first part by multiplying with  $x$. If I write this as an answer, would it suffice?